# $\vec{u}$,$\vec{v}$,$\vec{w} \in \mathbb{C}^{2017}$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

$\vec{u}$,$\vec{v}$,$\vec{w} \in \mathbb{C}^{2017}$  are linearly independent. Find $a \in \mathbb{C}$ such $a\vec{u}+i\vec{v}$, $a\vec{v}+i\vec{w}$, $a\vec{w}+i\vec{u}$ are linearly independent. If we can assume without loss of generality that $\vec{u} = [1, 0, \dots, 0]$, $\vec{v} = [0, 1, \dots, 0]$, $\vec{w} = [0, 0, 1, \dots, 0]$ then  $a\vec{u}+i\vec{v} = [a, i, 0 \dots, 0]$, $a\vec{v}+i\vec{w} = [0, a, i, 0 \dots, 0]$, $a\vec{w}+i\vec{u} = [i, 0, a, 0 \dots, 0]$. $det(\begin{pmatrix}
  a & 0 &  i \\
  i & a & 0 \\
0 & i & a \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots   \\
  0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}) = a^3-i$, so $a^3 \neq i$. Am I right?

Comment: Find *one* or find *all* such $a$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen all.

Comment: You are right, except you may be tempted to find the actual "forbidden" values of $a$, i.e. the cubic roots of $i$. There are three of them.

Comment: But how to justify that "we can assume without loss of generality(...)"?

Comment: Because any linearly independent set can be extended to form a basis, so there is a basis $(\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}, \ldots)$, and in that basis the coordinates are exactly as you've stated. Or, maybe better, forget about $\mathbb C^{2017}$ and look only at $\operatorname{span}(\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w})$, to save yourself from dealing with $2017\times 2017$ matrices. (Note: please fix your solution to actually use a $2017\times 2017$ matrix; what you're doing is a determinant of a $2017\times 3$ matrix, which is incorrect.)